# aApply CSS transition to CF7 Submit button

Tags: css, hover, css-transitions, contact-form-7, elementor

I'm trying to create the same type of CSS on hover transition on the Contact Form 7 button as I have on all the other buttons on the website. I tried to add the ease-in transition and translate from left to right, but I failed, since if I introduce it with :before, the background color goes over the button text as well.
You can see the example of the current state at the bottom of https://biocodis.com/test-page/, where I set two buttons one under another.
One button with the desired transition and the CF7 submit button above it.
What would be the best way to achieve this?

Here is the code I used:

```
button {
   position: relative;
   font-family: "Open Sans", Sans-serif;
   font-size: 18px;
   font-weight: 600;
   line-height: 18px;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
   padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
   border: none;
   background-color: #0D9FEC;
}

button span {
   z-index: 2;
}

button::before {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 0%;
   height: 100%;
   z-index: 1;
   background-color: rgba(242,157,23,1);
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
   -o-transition: all 0.3s;
   transition: all 0.3s;
   border-radius: 3px;
}

button:hover::before {
   opacity: 1;
   width: 100%;
}
```

As I mentioned, animation works the way I wanted it to, but the orange color goes over the text "send".

Thanks

Comment: Hi! Everyone on stack overflow likes **code** - you should put your CSS and the HTML of the form into your question.

Comment: @Djave Added, sorry about that. :)